# E_OUTOFMEMORY, Heap corruption

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, out-of-memory, runtimeexception, heap-corruption

What is wrong with this code:

```
    HRESULT AllocateAndFillOutParameters(DWORD * a_Attrib_Count, BSTR ** a_AttribName, DWORD** a_AttribId,BSTR** a_AttribDescription, BSTR** a_AttribDataType, 
    BSTR** a_AttribAdvanceDataType,DWORD** a_attribfieldlength, VECTOROFATTRIBUTESSTRUCT a_vectAttributes )
{
 HRESULT hr = S_OK;
 VECTOROFATTRIBUTESSTRUCT::iterator itr_vectCategory = a_vectAttributes.begin();

    // Memory Allocation 
     *a_Attrib_Count = a_vectAttributes.size();
    *a_AttribName = (BSTR*)CoTaskMemAlloc(*a_Attrib_Count * sizeof(BSTR));
    *a_AttribDescription = (BSTR*)CoTaskMemAlloc(*a_Attrib_Count * sizeof(BSTR));
    *a_AttribId = (DWORD*)CoTaskMemAlloc(*a_Attrib_Count * sizeof(DWORD));
    *a_AttribDataType = (BSTR*)CoTaskMemAlloc(*a_Attrib_Count * sizeof(BSTR));
    *a_AttribAdvanceDataType = (BSTR*)CoTaskMemAlloc(*a_Attrib_Count * sizeof(BSTR));
     *a_attribfieldlength = (DWORD*)CoTaskMemAlloc(*a_Attrib_Count * sizeof(DWORD));
    //

    for(int i=0 ;itr_vectCategory != a_vectAttributes.end(); itr_vectCategory++, i++)
    {
        *((*a_AttribName)+i) = SysAllocString(itr_vectCategory->m_strAttributeName.c_str());
        *((*a_AttribId)+i) = itr_vectCategory->m_dwAttributeId;
        *((*a_AttribDescription)+i) = SysAllocString(itr_vectCategory->m_strAttributeDescription.c_str());
        *((*a_AttribDataType)+i) = SysAllocString(itr_vectCategory->m_strAttributeDataType.c_str());
        *((*a_AttribAdvanceDataType)+i) = SysAllocString(itr_vectCategory->m_strAttributeAdvanceDataType.c_str());
        *((*a_attribfieldlength)+i) = (itr_vectCategory->m_dwAttributeFieldLength);

    }

 return hr;
}
```

It gives runtime exception of heap corruption , am i allocating in wrong way ?
Thanks for help.

Comment: Is this production code?

Comment: In the loop, should it really be `(*a_AttribName)+1`? Should you not add `i` instead of `1`?

Comment: Yes it is i, typing mistake here.

Comment: @Ehsank: Then better post the real code if you want the real problems to be found...

Comment: What is wrong with this code ? `DWORD***` really ? Is it part of a competition to see how many pointers you can fit on one line ? :P - edit .. aw my tired eyes saw one more *

Comment: where is DWORD*** ? these are references to BSTR & DWORD arrays. If i can do it with single pointers, i will appreciate ur guidance. Thanks

Comment: `*((*a_AttribName)+i)` can be changed to `(*a_AttribName)[i]`. Makes the code a bit easier to read.

Comment: i will upvote anyone who understands the code first time

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you where your error is, but I would suggest downloading the [Debugging Tools for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009) and then [reading the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff549557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on enabling Page Heap debugging using the `gflags` program which may allow you to catch the error where the heap corruption actually occurs.